# How can I make 1 million+ requests to an API in React appication?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to make a large number of post requests to an API and create "service tickets".
I have 3 types of services and I want to create packages of 50, 100, 500, 1k, 10k, and 1Million depending of what the user selects. (I am already storing that in a React State)

When I click I button I would like to send all the requests for the tickets at once, so we can have at the end:

service 1 = 1,000,000 tickets

service 2 = 500 tickets

service 3 = 1,000,000 tickets

total of Tickets = 2,000,500

I was wondering what is the best way to handle that amount of post requests in a single click? Any help will be very useful. Thanks!

This is the function I'm passing to my onClick event that creates a single ticket:

```js
const addTicket = async () => {

  try {
    const token = await getTokenSilently(); // from auth0 authentication
    let url = '.../endpoint' 
    const post = {
        createdFor: hostId, // here I put the id of the user I want to add the tickets
        service: typeOfService // Here I select one of the 3 types of services
    }
    
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(post),
      headers: {          
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+ token
      }
    });
    const responseData = await response.json();    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Im using:

-"react": "^16.13.1"

-the backend is running AWS Lambda

Comment: Why not make one request that simply says how many tickets you want to create and then let the backend take care of creating them in a batch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A million requests are not required, you can make an API endpoint where you can make  1 request with information of how many tickets you want and then handle the number of tickes on the server-side.

If you will make 1 million requests you will need a much better server and resources and you will be wasting a lot of unnecessary money

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is a way better idea